# only a part of the object is illuminated with directional light

Tags: lighting

[image]

Good afternoon. I have a problem with the lighting. everything works fine in Eevee, but in Cycles the light illuminates only part of the object, please tell me how it is possible to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=x9WrbkaE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/x9WrbkaE/)

Comment: You really should show a screenshot of what it looks like in EEVEE as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Cycles Direct Lighting Clamping to an odd value of 0.03.

[image]

If I change it to what I use my default (0.0) or to 1.0, the rendering looks okay.

[image]

I also notice that your light level of 5w is rather small.

result: [image]

Comment: thank you so much!)